# Mysql Error Handling

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Is there a way to get the mysql error string message when we only know the code number of the error, taken by `mysql_errno()` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about what sort of error fired (see e.g.: [server error messages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html)). But you cant associate the error code to the detail error message. So the mapping will give you the type of error which happened but:

```
mysql_error()
```

will always give more information in addition to mysql_errno.

Comment: I see, at least can I get the type somehow?

Comment: You may get the type by reverse mapping the error code to the associated string template in the file share/errmsg.txt of your mysql distribution. Another option would be the evaluation of the logs if you have an associated timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

There can be server or client errors.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-handling.html

Comment: I mean server error ofcourse. But is there a command that returns the string message by the error number?

Comment: I don't know of a command for this. But you can put them in a table and based on the error no. take the string. Check also here: http://www.briandunning.com/error-codes/?source=MySQL

Answer (score 1):

The command [`mysql_errno()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php) doesn't just return a number, in most cases it is used hand in hands with [`mysql_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). You can use [`mysql_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to return the text of the error message from previous MySQL operation.

If you encounter a case where it doesn't return some text, refer this section in the Mysql-documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-handling.html

Comment: So I can get only the last error that happened and not a string of an error that happened sometime before, and I only know the number of this error?

Comment: Exactly. For that php would need kindof a library for all mysql errors, and that -at least from my perspective- ain't the purpose of php.